# Layout not changing when parent (UIView) size is changed

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, constraints

I have a `UIView` and inside this `UIView` I have another `UIView`, lets say parent and child `UIView`. I have set height and width of parent `UIView` to 400 in `storyboard` and set child view `constraint` to take 8px margin  from top, left right and bottom from its superview.

But When I change size of parent view to 200, size of child view remain same. I have tried this in both `viewdidload` and `viewdidappear`

```
CGRect frm = self.mainTimerView.frame;
frm.size.width = size;
frm.size.height = size;
self.mainTimerView.frame = frm;
```

when I change parent view to 200 child should set it self to `200-16` height and width according to constraints.

Comment: You are taking size from "mainTimerView" and then again setting "mainTimerView" with same size. How can it change then.

Comment: call [parent layoutIfNeeded]

Comment: Wasim I am changing its width and height in 2nd and 3rd line then assigning it again to mainTimerView

Comment: arshadkc I am trying it

Comment: @Yawar you need to take outlet for constraint then change the constraint value .

Comment: @yawar, Then you call it in -(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews.

Comment: Making outlet of height and changing its value from code solved my problem, plus calling layoutIfNeeded function on parent view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not mix using uiconstraint with using frame.If you want to change the size when using uiconstraint, you should make the outlet of the constraint, and then change the constraint's constant property.Call `layoutIfNeeded`,then you can get the right frame.

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *mainTimerView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *mainTimerViewHeightConstraint;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    NSLog(@"%@",@(self.mainTimerView.frame.size.width));

    self.mainTimerViewHeightConstraint.constant = 100;

    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    NSLog(@"%@",@(self.mainTimerView.frame.size.height));
}

@end
```

Calling `layoutIfNeeded` aim to to force the layout of subviews before drawing, then `viewDidLayoutSubviews` will be called. Note that you can get the correct frame in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. In other words, you can get the right frame after `viewDidLayoutSubviews` has been called.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.mainTimerView.frame));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1) Change the `height` constraint of the `mainview`.

2) Call the `layoutIfNeeded` method.

3) Do it on `viewDidAppear`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling `setNeedsLayout` on the parent view? This call is used to ask a view to layout its subviews. From the `setNeedsLayout's` discussion section:

> Call this method on your application’s main thread when you want to adjust the layout of a view’s subviews. This method makes a note of the request and returns immediately. Because this method does not force an immediate update, but instead waits for the next update cycle, you can use it to invalidate the layout of multiple views before any of those views are updated. This behavior allows you to consolidate all of your layout updates to one update cycle, which is usually better for performance.

Calling `layoutIfNeeded` might be another option. But according to the docs, it forces an immediate layout, and therefore does not provide the consolidation benefit gained by using `setNeedsLayout`.

`layoutIfNeeded` documention:

> Lays out the subviews immediately.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Plz create the IBOutlet of height Constraint of parent view.

```
IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *RedViewHeightconstraint;

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
     RedViewHeightconstraint.constant = 500;
}
```

it will work for you

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create IBOutlets of constraints of height and width of mainTimerView. Once you do so add these lines of code :

constraintOuterViewHt.constant = 200
constraintOuterViewWidth.constant = 200

You don't need to do anything else.
[Check screen shot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIcz6.png)